# Baseにあるviewのalphaを下げると、上にあるviewも一緒に透過してしまう

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

お世話になります
これはもしかしたら解決策はないのかもしれないのですが、
一応聞いてみました

ベースにあるviewをalpha0.7で設定してるのですが、そうすると一緒に上のボタンもalpha値が0.7になってしまいます。
これって回避手段はないのでしょうか

こんなかんじです
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

デザイン上の制約が出るかもしれませんが、ベースにあるviewのalphaは1.0のままにしてviewの背景色のalphaを0.7に設定すると乗っているボタンに影響しないと思います。

Comment: なるほどです。この方法で試してみます！

Answer (score 0):

こんな感じになりました。
0.7でほぼ、透過している色が白かどうかすらわからないほど、透過しますが、こんなもんなのでしょうか

コードは以下になってます

```
//背景色のアルファを透過させる
    self.toolbar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.70)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]